# Querying distinct timestamps from column in Google's Big Query

Tags: sql, database, timestamp, google-bigquery

I am working to select data from a price database. The rows I want to query are the ones which occur every whole minute, and distinctly. So, if there's a minute that has two prices, I would rather the first price.

Here's what the data looks like this this VVV query:

SELECT price, timestamp
FROM [database] 
WHERE stock="appl" AND second(timestamp) = 0
ORDER BY timestamp

Result:

Row price   timestamp
1   0.097947    2018-02-14 03:42:00.000 UTC
2   0.09796 2018-02-14 03:43:00.000 UTC
3   0.097959    2018-02-14 03:45:00.000 UTC
4   0.097969    2018-02-14 03:46:00.000 UTC
5   0.097984    2018-02-14 03:47:00.000 UTC
6   0.097986    2018-02-14 03:47:00.000 UTC  (Duplicate time ^)
7   0.097899    2018-02-14 03:48:00.000 UTC
8   0.097927    2018-02-14 03:49:00.000 UTC
9   0.097984    2018-02-14 03:50:00.000 UTC
10  0.097995    2018-02-14 03:51:00.000 UTC
11  0.097972    2018-02-14 03:52:00.000 UTC
12  0.097924    2018-02-14 03:53:00.000 UTC
13  0.097935    2018-02-14 03:54:00.000 UTC

When I add "GROUP BY price, timestamp", the data has no difference.

I want distinct timestamps. So, for this case the result should be:

Row price   timestamp
1   0.097947    2018-02-14 03:42:00.000 UTC
2   0.09796 2018-02-14 03:43:00.000 UTC
3   0.097959    2018-02-14 03:45:00.000 UTC
4   0.097969    2018-02-14 03:46:00.000 UTC
5   0.097984    2018-02-14 03:47:00.000 UTC
6   0.097899    2018-02-14 03:48:00.000 UTC
7   0.097927    2018-02-14 03:49:00.000 UTC
8   0.097984    2018-02-14 03:50:00.000 UTC
9   0.097995    2018-02-14 03:51:00.000 UTC
10  0.097972    2018-02-14 03:52:00.000 UTC
11  0.097924    2018-02-14 03:53:00.000 UTC
12  0.097935    2018-02-14 03:54:00.000 UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(price), timestamp
FROM [database]
WHERE stock = 'appl' AND second(timestamp) = 0
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "first" price, unless another column specifies that value.  You can get one price per timestamp with something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(price), timestamp
FROM [database]
WHERE stock = 'appl' AND second(timestamp) = 0
GROUP BY timestamp;
```

If you do have another column with the ordering, then you can use array agg and choose the first value.

Comment: I like the MIN() aggregation. It's the approach I think will work best, but "Error: (L1:26): (L1:38): SELECT clause has mix of aggregations 'MinPrice' and fields 'timestamp' without GROUP BY clause" was the error I got trying to get the output.

Comment: Actually your method is perfect with an addition of "GROUP BY timestamp".  Do you know if there's a function to get the mode of the values instead of min or max?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and assumes your `ts` field is of timestamp type)

```
SELECT 
  ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] price,
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, MINUTE) ts 
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
WHERE stock = 'appl'
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2
```

Note: I use `ts` instead of `timestamp` as I prefer not using keywords as column names